# Error saving Eclipse project to Google Drive

Tags: google-plugin-eclipse

I have a newly-created Apps Script project in Drive which I successfully imported into Eclipse via the Google Plugin.

I made some edits and hit Save, and I get this:

```
Error saving Eclipse project TestProject to Drive (file ID: 18Xhe...)
com.google.gdt.eclipse.drive.driveapi.DriveWritingException: Server error while storing project in Drive.
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.drive.driveapi.DriveServiceFacade.writeProject(DriveServiceFacade.java:222)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.drive.DriveEclipseProjectMediator.performDriveUpdate(DriveEclipseProjectMediator.java:446)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.drive.DriveEclipseProjectMediator$2.run(DriveEclipseProjectMediator.java:406)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Internal Error",
    "reason" : "internalError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Internal Error"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.drive.driveapi.DriveServiceFacade.writeProject(DriveServiceFacade.java:219)
    ... 5 more
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Jeffery

Answer (score 3):

I see the same error message as well. The problem started occurring a few hours ago.

I've reported this at https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=284&thanks=284&ts=1401349699

Comment: I voted for the issue you reported. Hopefully more people will pile on and it will get noticed/fixed.

Comment: i'm surprised that more people haven't reported the problem.

Comment: Me, too. Eclipse is completely unusable for me on this project, right now. Boo!